# Object visible in preview disappears when I render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I had accidently deleted the Render Layers and Composite nodes in the Compositing nodes section. When I discovered this problem (as it wouldn't render of course) I re-added those nodes. However now when it renders it only renders the white cap part and not the glass bottle of my scene. Any suggestions please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the camera icons on the outliner. When the camera icons are disabled, the object is disabled from rendering.

Click on the funnel icon on the top right and enable different filters.

The **Eye** icon determines visibility in the 3d viewport.

The **Monitor** icon disables the object in all viewports.

The **Camera** icon determines if the object is rendered or not.

[image]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner/interface.html

For version 1.79 or older the controls are like this:

[image]

Comment: I should be banned from using Blender.  Sorry.

Comment: Not at all, we've all made that error at one point or another. ; )

Comment: @Marc, one practice you might find useful in the future is to devise a more robust naming scheme than "cylinder", "cylinder.001", "cylinder.002", and "cylinder.003", It's not such a big deal in the current project, but imagine that you're called upon to model a bottling facility, where there are 16,594 bottles present, which pass along a [roller conveyor](http://www.titanconveyors.com/Portals/0/Images/products/roller_gravity-LG.jpg) for some distance, so that your have 105 k cylinders in your scene. Just my .0002 worth; keep the change

Comment: @brass All suggestions appreciated. Thank you