# Rigid body simulation is not rendered

Tags: rendering, rigid-body-simulation

I've made a simple rigid body simulation and when I try to render it, it does not work. It gives the same results as if there was no camera, however I replaced a camera with the new one but the problems remains. Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object visible in preview disappears when I render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50890/object-visible-in-preview-disappears-when-i-render)

Comment: Not the case, I have way more objects than you can see here, those are enabled, even if they were disabled it would render a dark scene instead of something what has been rendered in 0 seconds

Comment: If that is not the case please go through the answers in this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: If you have more information please [edit] your question so that you can get better asnswer

Comment: I have solved the same issue baking the simulation in the scene properties