# Object not appearing in Render View or final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, objects

[image]Thanks for reading.

I started sculpting a mesh and noticed I wasn't in Cycles. After switching, the object no longer appears in the final render or in Render View. The object shows up just fine in the other 3D view options.

Things I have checked:
 - The object is selected for viewing in the Outliner. 
 - The shaders are linked to the Material Output and Alpha is set to 1.
 - Viewed by camera in cycles is checked in the Object tab.

If anyone knows a solution to this issue or the reason behind it, the info would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
Image as requested.
Camera is checked and in position.
Shader and Texture Nodes Connected to Object's Material Output.
3 Point lighting using soft hemi's.
All objects (even lamps currently, sigh) are on same layer.

Comment: *"The object is selected for viewing in the Outliner"* this doesn't mean it's enabled for rendering. Did you check camera icon? DId you check materials? (which are not converted to Cycles materials dy default) Did you check lighting? Your question is too vague without any screenshots or more info about your project.

Comment: is the camera icon enabled in the outliner? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50890/object-visible-in-preview-disappears-when-i-render/50891#50891

Comment: Mr Zak, yes, camera is checked, materials scanned over in materials tab and in node editor, lighting is fine. Hope this covers my bases but if I need to give more info I will.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Layers and see what is wrong. Generaly this is the problem. Maybe your object is no more on the render layer

Comment: Object can't be not included in at least one render layer

Comment: @MrZak I think he's trying to say that the object may be on the wrong layer, i.e. not on the layer being rendered.

Comment: I have attached an image of the situation, but the objects are indeed visible in the layer and the correct layer is selected.