# Render Preview is fine, but a plane is missing on the final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Render preview looks like this [image: render preview]

But when I hit render, I get this image [image]

Does anyone know why? I'm using filmic blender color management if that makes a difference.

Comment: Has the plane been disabled to render (camera icon on the outliner)?, Is the ray visibility for Camera enabled in Cycles settings for the object?, Are you using any lightpath nodes to determine visibility of the missing object?

Comment: Yeah that fixed it and I feel dumb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) and [One Object won't Show up in Final Render even though it shows up in the Preview Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50890/object-visible-in-preview-disappears-when-i-render/50891#50891)